# Deploy MEAN Stack app on any server I want

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have this MEAN Stack app working fine on development mode. I want to deploy it on my company's server, but the problem was all the videos about deploying MEAN apps were even on Digital Ocean, Azure or Heroku.
Is there anyway I deploy my app on a server I choose ?

Comment: You know how to install your app on your local machine, so what exactly is your problem installing it on a different machine (the server)?

Comment: I said deploy it ( production mode )

Comment: But deploying is just installing it on a server and run it. How do you want to trigger the deployment? Usually, the server pulls the repository (if it is a git repo you just use `git pull`), then you call npm install and npm start. If you got any other dependencies you need to install them on the server too and of course you need to set up a mongodb instance.

Comment: Okay dude I'll try and feed you back

Comment: Which angular version you are using??

Comment: I'm using Angular 5

Answer (score 1):

The traditional web apps runs on Apache

for deploying NodeJS based app, like MEAN Stack or MERN Stack etc. its must that you have root access to the server, means you must have vps host and it wouldn't work with 'shared hosting plans',

So if you have dedicated server, then you will login to that through SSH and install Node and NPM, then you can deploy application freely.

> The good new is that Godaddy is working to provide 'out-of-the-box'
>   hosting for nodejs too, hope that's soon.